# Removing all scroll events from element

Tags: javascript, scroll, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I need to disable every scroll events from an element.

Tried this function but "someFunction" is not accessible from the place where I executes my JS so i cannot use this one.
Moreover, my element has others event listeners that i don't want to see disapear like it should if I had duplicated my element.

```
element.removeEventListener('scroll', someFunction);
```

Anybody helps ?

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas

Comment: you can try disable scroll with css. set `overflow: hidden` on element you want to disable.

Comment: @Layhout Tried to apply overflow: hidden on my div but it changes nothing. Event stills executes

Comment: You can't remove specific event listener without access to the function. You can however remove all event listeners in a patchy way by cloning the element.

Comment: @IT goldman Is there a way to get this function ?

Comment: Where is `someFunction`? you said you don't have access to it.

Comment: You are right, i don't have access to it. I was asking if there is a way to get every listeners concerning a element.